# Updating UITableView on Web Service Async Callback

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I am using the following code to invoke the `[self.tableView reloadData]` method inside the `dispatch_async` on the main thread. It works fine and as expected.

```
-(void) setup
{
    _genres = [NSMutableArray array];

    [[MyAppClient sharedClient] getGenres:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        [responseObject enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            Genre *genre = [[Genre alloc] initWithDictionary:obj];
            [_genres addObject:genre];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.tableView reloadData];

            });

        }];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    }];

}
```

Even if I use it without the `dispatch_async` call the `UITableView` reloads just fine. My question is that if there anyway benefit of `dispatch_async` in the above scenario.

My reason is that since I am updating the `UI` which runs on the main thread and that is why I am using `dispatch_async(main_queue,block)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always want to make sure that you do UI updates on the main thread, so you are right about doing the `dispatch_async`. One thing about your code, though: you're doing the dispatch_async to reload the table inside the block, so it is doing it for every single execution of the block. You only need to do it once, so I would suggest moving the `dispatch_async` to below the call to `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. This also ensures that you're not updating _genres on the background thread while the main thread is getting it to update the table.

Comment: Good call on moving the call outside the enumeration. I overlooked that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You must update the UI on the main thread. If the response block is called on a background thread then your use of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` is correct as well as required.